# advantage of using Javascript closure on events to define a click event

Tags: javascript

I've seen code written as the following 2 ways in Javascript:

`A.`

```
SomeObject.prototype.hideElement = function(e, element){
    e.stopPropagation();
    hide(element);
}
```

`B.`

```
SomeObject.prototype.hideElement = function(element){
    return function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        hide(element);
    }
}
```

What is the advantage of using `A` vs. `B` and when would one be more relevant than the other?

Comment: Have you tried actually *using* them?

Comment: They do 2 very different things.

Answer (score 1):

This is way too long for a comment.

I wasn't trying to be condescending (nor was I one of the downvotes). I meant the fact that it should be obvious to anyone who tried to use them that the first cannot work being directly attached as an event handler whereas the second returns a function that can. They don't even take their arguments in the same order or return the same thing. It may be helpful to think in terms of types:

```
// option1 :: (Event, HTMLElement) -> Undefined
// option2 :: HTMLElement -> Event -> Undefined
```

To translate, option1 is a function which takes a Tuple(Event, HTMLElement) and returns Undefined. Option2 is a function which takes an HTMLElement and returns a function that takes an Event and returns Undefined.

Looking at the type signatures makes it pretty obvious that although these functions both hide an HTMLElement, they cannot be used the same way. Looking at the signature for JavaScript event handlers:

```
// handler :: Event -> *
```

Where `*` means any type, we see from the type signatures above that only option2, HTMLElement -> **Event -> Undefined**, fits.

Now we're wading into opinion territory (and I'm assuming the opinion-based aspect is part of why you got downvoted), but I would argue that the second version is better than the first. Because the first cannot work directly as an event handler, but takes an event as an argument, that means its going to have to be called by an event handler and have the event passed in. Passing event objects around is usually an antipattern in JS.

The second version is also better (again IMHO) because of [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application): it can lead to code reuse:

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('some-element');
var hider = option2(someElement); // remember, returns a function
var button = document.getElementById('hide-button');
button.addEventListener('click', hider);
button.addEventListener('keydown', hider); // accessibility handler, note reuse
```

What if there's more than one element whose interactions cause 'some-element' to be hidden? Hopefully you're starting to see the usefulness here.

As a final note about your passive-aggressive comment above, sometimes you will ask what seems to you to be a perfectly sensible question, but you missed something. Something that, in retrospect, makes the answer somewhat obvious. Or one that you think has an objective answer, but is actually opinion-based (and therefor not suitable for SO). People will downvote/comment. It happens. Don't take it personally. Programming is *hard*, and we all make mistakes. Try to separate the *content* of the feedback from its emotional impact, the latter is unlikely to do you any good.

Comment: Good answer. What syntax are you using for functional type notation?

Comment: @Pavlo its kinda-sorta Hindley-Milner. The '::' means 'has type' the arrows denote functions, etc. I annotate most of my JS code this way as a mental aid, especially when I'm coming back to it after working on something else for 3 months.

Comment: Also, two arguments are not the same as tuple.

Comment: @Pavlo quite true, but I'm adapting a notation borrowed from a generally curried environment. I meant it more that they are one conceptual unit rather than a data structure.